# Why can matrix multiplication be reordered in a trace of a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through this page: https://rich-d-wilkinson.github.io/MATH3030/3-5-lowrank.html.

I'm quite confused by the part immediately after 3.1 where it proves it is invariant under rotation by an orthogonal matrix. It gives a simple reason that $tr(UAA^{\top}U{\top})=tr(UU^{\top}AA^{\top})$. Why can we reorder the operation here to bring U to the front?

Comment: This is the cyclic property of the trace function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Cyclic_property